# Adding a checkbox to the theme customizer

Tags: theme-options

When trying to add a checkbox to the theme customizer it seems to be 'always' selected. If you try to deselect it you cannot, almost as if there is some JS code forcing it to stay selected.

I am using serialized theme options and everything is hooked up correctly. Code is similar to the following (triggered via the 'customize_register' hook):

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( mytheme_options[chk_hide_description], array(
    'default'        => false,
    'type'           => 'option',
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options' )
);

$wp_customize->add_control( 'display_header_text', array(
    'settings' => mytheme_options[chk_hide_description],
    'label'    => __( 'Hide site description' ),
    'section'  => 'title_tagline',
    'type'     => 'checkbox',
) );
```

Same issue reported here: http://ottopress.com/2012/how-to-leverage-the-theme-customizer-in-your-own-themes/#div-comment-11254.

Comment: hey, did you resolve this issue? Same here. It gets somehow checked via JS. The comment on ottopress with 'unique ID' didn't help for me.

Comment: My issue was resolved when I made sure the ID used in $wp_customize->add_control() was unique.

Comment: @dgwyer, please, add your solution as an Answer, so this Question don't remains in the "Unanswered" list.

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 7):

Checkbox is possible. A example, I hope this help you.

At first, you must define the setting, via `add_setting`, important is the parameter `type` with value `option`. After this, control the field via `add_control`and set the parameter `type` to `checkbox`. Alternative, it is possible to use `select`. If I add a default value via `std`, then work it, also without this parameter. Alternative works also fine, if I add the choice's parameter with the values 1 and 0. But on the tests, works fine, if I set the param only to `checkbox`. You find the source inside my project, see link below.

Also, you can debug the output on value string on the line 246 in the wp-includes/class-wp-customize-control.php; maybe it helps.

debug:

```php
case 'checkbox':
    var_dump( $this->value() );
```

Example:

```php
// Add settings for output description
$wp_customize->add_setting( $this->option_key . '[echo_desc]', array(
    'default'    => $defaults['echo_desc'],
    'type'       => 'option',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options'
) );
        
// Add control and output for select field
$wp_customize->add_control( $this->option_key . '_echo_desc', array(
    'label'      => __( 'Display Description', 'documentation' ),
    'section'    => 'title_tagline',
    'settings'   => $this->option_key . '[echo_desc]',
    'type'       => 'checkbox',
    'std'        => '1'
) );
```

See the result of this source.
[image: screenshot depicting the checkbox in the WordPress customizer]

You find a working result in my theme [Documentation, hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/bueltge/Documentation/blob/master/inc/theme-customize.php).

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar issue, and it turned out that setting `'type' => 'option'` for `add_setting` was the cause.

Removing this solved my problem, and below is what I am currently using and it works just fine.

```
$wp_customize->add_section('footer_social_media_section' , array(
    'title'     => __('Footer Social Media', 'dd_theme'),
    'priority'  => 1020
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('show_footer_facebook', array(
    'default'    => '1'
));

$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'show_footer_facebook',
        array(
            'label'     => __('Show Facebook Link', 'dd_theme'),
            'section'   => 'footer_social_media_section',
            'settings'  => 'show_footer_facebook',
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sanitize_callback` helped me:

```
$setting = 'display_note_site';

$wp_customize->add_setting( $setting, [
    'type' => 'option',
    'transport' => $transport,
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_checkbox',
] );

$wp_customize->add_control( $setting, [
    'section' => $section,
    'label'   => 'Display a notification?',
    'type'    => 'checkbox',
] );

function sanitize_checkbox( $checked ) {
    return $checked == 1 ? 1 : '';
}
```

Using:

```
$display_note_site = get_option('display_note_site');

if( $display_note_site ) {
    // html output
}
```